# Aggregate img url function not functional with one blog built with blogger

Tags: php, wordpress, function, rss, blogger

I am trying to aggregate the latest posts by several blogs using their rss feed. The code below is working fine for most platforms including blogg.se . Although it is strangely not working with a blog from blogg.se called, http://sofiasinredning.blogg.se/index.rss .

```
  function wpse_187819_get_feed_html( $url, $bloggauthor ) {
if ( !is_admin() ) {
if ( is_wp_error( $rss = fetch_feed( $url ) ) )
    return;

$maxitems  = $rss->get_item_quantity( 1 );
$rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );

$html = '<ul class="rss-items rss-old" id="wows-feeds">';
if (!empty($bloggauthor)) {
    $authorcredit = '<span class="field-label">' . $bloggauthor . '</span>'; 
} else { $authorcredit = '<span class="field-label"> Name </span>';}

if ( $maxitems ) {
    foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) {
        $title     = esc_attr( $item->get_title() );
        $link      = esc_url( $item->get_permalink() );
        $stringses = $item-> get_description();
        global $wp_query;
        $lengthses = '';
            if ( $wp_query->is_page ) {
                $lengthses = '100';
            } elseif ( $wp_query->is_home ) {
                $lengthses = '100';
            } elseif ( $wp_query->is_single ) {
                $lengthses = '700';
            } elseif ( $wp_query->is_category ) {
                $lengthses = '100';
            } elseif ( $wp_query->is_tag ) {
                $lengthses = '50';
            } elseif ( $wp_query->is_tax ) {
                $lengthses = '30';
            } elseif ( $wp_query->is_archive ) {
                if ( $wp_query->is_day ) {
                    $lengthses = '60';
                } elseif ( $wp_query->is_month ) {
                    $lengthses = '60';
                } elseif ( $wp_query->is_year ) {
                    $lengthses = '60';
                } elseif ( $wp_query->is_author ) {
                    $lengthses = '400';
                } else {
                    $lengthses = '500';
                }
            } elseif ( $wp_query->is_search ) {
                $lengthses = '400';
            } elseif ( $wp_query->is_404 ) {
                $lengthses = '';
            }
        $date      = $item->get_date('F Y');

$suffix = '&hellip;';
$short_desc = trim(str_replace(array("&nbsp;", "/r", "/n", "/t"), '',     strip_tags($stringses)));
$desc = trim(substr($short_desc, 0, $lengthses));
$lastchar = substr($desc, 0, 1);
  if ($lastchar == '.' || $lastchar == '!' || $lastchar == '?') $suffix='';
      $desc .= $suffix;

        $html .= '<li class="item"><a target="_blanc" href="' . $link . '" title="' . $title . '">'; 
            if ( preg_match( '/<img.+?src="(.+?)"/', $item->get_content(), $matches ) ) {
                $html .= '<span class="rss-image"><div class="square attachment-special" style="background-image: url(' . $matches[1] . ');"><img style="opacity: 0;" class="attachment-special" src="' . $matches[1] . '"/></div></span></a>';
            }
            elseif ($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure()) {
                $html .= '<span class="rss-image"><div class="square attachment-special" style="background-image: url(' . $enclosure->get_link() . ');"><img style="opacity: 0;" class="attachment-special" src="' . $enclosure->get_link() . '"/></div></span></a>';
            }
            else {
                $html .= '<img class="attachment-special" src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/logga/500x500.png"/></a>';
            } 
            $html .= '<div class="item-content"><h5 class="pink-text">' . $authorcredit . '</h5><a target="_blanc" href="' . $link . '" title="' . $title . '"><span class="data"><h1 class="entry-title">' . $title . '</h1></span></a>';
          $html .= '<p>' . $desc . '</p>';


        $html .= '</li>';
    }

} else {
    $html .= '<li>No items</li>';
}


$html .= '</ul>';

echo $html;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: blogg.se is a different Blogging platform. Not related to Google's Blogger platform

Comment: Thanks for answer @PrayagVerma, My fault - it is working fine with blogger and all the other blogs from blogg.se! Her blog is the only one not working!...